# Overriding a parent class

Tags: java

I have my *Pet* super class which then has a *Dog* subclass, and a particular method in my super class is getSpecies(). In my subclass I want to be able to return `super.getSpecies()`, but also return another variable (in this case, smell) inside that method as well.

**Super class:**

```
public class Pet {
    protected int lifeSpan;
    protected  String species, name, interaction;

    public Pet(){
    }

    public Pet(int lifeSpan, String species, String name){
        this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
        this.species = species;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final float costs(float cost){
        return cost;
    }

    public void setSpecies(String species){
        this.species = species;
    }

    public String getSpecies(){
        return this.species;
    }
}
```

**Subclass "Dog":**

```
public class Dog extends Pet{
    protected String smell;
    private String species;

    public Dog(String smell){
        super(15, "Dog", "Rex");
        this.smell = smell;
    }

    public Dog(){

    }

    public void setSmell(String smell){
        this.smell = smell;
    }

    public String getSpecies(){
       super.getSpecies();
       smell = "high"; //Meant to deliberately set it to "High". How am I to return this?
    }

    public String getSmell(){
        return this.smell;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You can't return two values from a method. But may I know the reason why you can't use `getSmell()` method separately?

Comment: My question is as follows: Override the String getSpecies() method so that the smell variable is also
displayed.

Comment: So basically I must override the species method in my parent class and ADD the private variable in my subclass to it

Comment: So, I guess that means that `getSpecies()` must return the species *concatenated* with the smell.

Comment: the getSmell method is specific to dog.  the private member variable goes in the dog class.  the public getSmell() method goes in the dog class.

Comment: Yea I presume I must return getSpecies() concatinated with getSmell or just smell variable itself(Not too sure!)

Comment: My question is how to return super.getSpecies() concatinated with smell in the dog class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return two values in a single function. What you have to do is use your getter for the smell member variable instead.

```
public class Dog extends Pet{
    protected String smell;
    private String species;

    public Dog(String smell){
        super(15, "Dog", "Rex");
        this.smell = smell;
    }

    public Dog(){

    }

    public void setSmell(String smell){
        this.smell = smell;
    }

    public String getSpecies(){
       super.getSpecies();
    }

    public String getSmell(){
        return this.smell;
    }

}
```

Then let's say you want both species and smell, you have to check if the pet is in fact a dog, and if it is, you can safely cast it as a dog and use the specific methods of the Dog class.

```
if ( pet instanceof Dog ) {
    String species = pet.getSpecies();
    String smell = (Dog)pet.getSmell();
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, very interesting approach! Trying to stick to getters/setters for now however. Thanks :-)

Comment: I highly recommend not concatenating different variables in a single return. It is bad practice, is very unclear and clearly not what the `getSpecies()` method is for.

Comment: Get your point.. mind explaining to me how where you input the above condition in the Dog class I posted?

Comment: Well you should use it at the place where you want to access both the smell and the species. You put the entire condition instead of the single line `pet.getSpecies()` in your first program.

Answer (score -2):

First things first: When calling `super.getSpecies()` you should save or hand over it's return value somewhere. Then you might consider concatenating this return string an your second return value (`high`) like this:

```
public String getSpecies(){
   return "high " + super.getSpecies();
}
```

But:

- the return of that `high dog` doesn't make much sense IMO.
- a getter is expected to return only one value, the one it's name comes from.

There is no ather way to return multiple values except for passing objects that take the results as arguements. But that solution would be far away from a simple getter.

You should consider (like [Pilibobby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2136376/philibobby) pointed out in his comment below) using two different getters in your case, `getSpecies()` and `getSmell()`, and combine their results at the place you are calling them from.

Comment: That would print highDog.

Comment: Alright thanks, understood, maybe I interpreted the question wrong :)

Comment: @Booch You are welcome (and welcome to SO as well :)  ). You may mark an anser as accepted if they satisfied you, or check out other ansers if they can help you more.

Comment: Thanks again, I'd kindly ask you to review the answer below as doing this is bad practice?

Comment: That is not a good practice. A getter is expected to return the value of the variable not a concatenated value.

Comment: @Philibobby Thanks for pointing that out! Edited my answer giving credits to you :)